# How can I start IntelliJ IDEA remotely as an X Windows application, if the server is Mac?

Tags: macos, docker, intellij-idea, ssh, x11

I had success to start it, but through a Docker container, ugly but works.

The setup is, old mac with good keyboard = X server.
The new mac with broken keys: X11Forwarding yes.

On the server I tried idea, it starts only on the server. No idea.sh in bin.

Downloading a container with linux, setting its DISPLAY, and IntelliJ starts on the other mac.
Can something be done so that the nice IntelliJ app starts on another mac?

I tried remoting (screen sharing, team viewer) and they are too slow to react, even on LAN (the trackpad is the problem, the screen itself and keyboard are snappy).

Also with Docker it is a bit tricky to keep it alive, commit it, be careful not to loose the state (even if the projects are mounted on volumes with host).

Are you aware of a Linux VirtualBox that would be suitable to install Java, Scala & IntelliJ ? Ubuntu? Debian? Rethorical question, I guess either can work. Port forwarding for X11. Somehow I would need 2 forwardings, or maybe it would work the way Docker works, maybe both are bridges and see in the LAN. The Docker container sure seems to directly see the other IP.

Comment: Ubuntu Docker container with tigervnc work just fine and Mac has built-in vnc viewer.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed only an OS that communicates over X protocol, such as Linux can be used (via Docker container, Virtual Machine, etc). MacOS uses VNC as protocol.